# How can I cut only necessary part of string in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, ruby-on-rails-3

For exsmple:

I have: new.string-@22/4576/:thisneedtoo.ffgFhhA.pdf?7765trimsAskellYo2212

And I need only: string-@22/4576/:thisneedtoo.ffgFhhA.pdf?

Comment: Nothing to do with Rails, this is pure Ruby. Also, the answer will be just a guess unless you define a bit more precisely what "necessary part" means for you.

Comment: Cut everything after and including the question mark-what's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

If the string always starts with "new.", and you want everything after that up to and including the question mark, a simple [Ruby regular expression](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Regexp.html) will pull it out:

```
match_data = /\Anew\.([^?]+\?).+\Z/.match(s)
match_data[1]
 => "string-@22/4576/:thisneedtoo.ffgFhhA.pdf?"
```

I would start with an easy-to-understand regular expression and once it is working, refine and optimize the expression and add error checking.

Comment: Fun syntax almost no-one uses: `s[/\Anew\.([^?]+\?).+\Z/, 1]`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Amadan !